# overriding dataframe row value with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
|name     |favorite animal|
|---------|---------------|
|Mary     |cat            |
|Benny    |shark          |
|Jack     |dog            |
|Becca    |sheep          |
|Christie |dinosaur       |
```

df2:

```
|name     |favorite animal|
|---------|---------------|
|Mary     |dog            |
|Benny    |fish           |
|Christie |monkey         |
```

Is there anyway I can replace the value in df1 by value in df2 by matching on name between df1 and df2 (names that appear in df2 will update "favorite animal on df1) so that the output looks like

```
|name     |favorite animal|
|---------|---------------|
|Mary     |dog            |
|Benny    |fish           |
|Jack     |dog            |
|Becca    |sheep          |
|Christie |monkey         |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a zip list of `name` and `favorite animal` for df2 and use `replace`:

```
lst = list(zip(df2['name'], df2['favorite animal']))
df1['favorite animal'] = df1['favorite animal'].replace(lst)
```